# Why doesn't 'find' prune the way I think it should?

Tags: macos, unix, find

I'm running MacOSX 10.5.8

I run the following:

```
~/Sites/jjprof/trunk/content > find . -type d -name '*svn' -prune
./.svn
./resources/.svn
./resources/sitewide/.svn
./temporary/.svn
./users/.svn
./users/avatars/.svn
```

I would expect this command to *ignore* all the .svn subdirectories; instead it displays them.

```
find . -name '*svn' -prune
```

does the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -type d -path '.svn' -prune -o -print
```

From [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) under the section on `-name`:

> To ignore a directory and the files under it, use  `-prune`; see an example in the description of
> `-path`.

Under the section on `-path`:

> To  ignore  a whole directory tree, use `-prune` rather
>                 than checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip  the
>                 directory  `src/emacs`  and  all files and directories under it,
>                 and print the names of the other files found, do something  like
>                 this:
>
> ```
>              find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
> ```

From the "Examples" section:

> However, the `-prune` action itself returns true, so the
>          following `-o` ensures that the right hand side  is  evaluated  only  for
>          those  directories  which didn't get pruned (the contents of the pruned
>          directories are not even visited, so their  contents  are  irrelevant).

Comment: This is indeed the right way to use `-prune`, and a good explanation. However, `-name .svn` is the right way to select `.svn` subdirectories (`-name '*svn' or `-path '*svn'` would match extra files).

Comment: This does not in fact work.  You need to use `'*/.svn'` as the path name; otherwise, it will not match `./.svn`, `./subdir/svn`, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

*find* manual states tha prune "ignores the preceding path ..." so the command should be

```
find . -prune -type d -name '*svn'
```

This is because you can have something like

```
find -path . -name '*svn' -o -path './notimportantdir' -prune
```

which finds '*svn' in current path **except** those under *notimportantdir*