# The correct way to use find prune

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, syntax

Facing the same problem as [Why doesn't 'find' prune the way I think it should?](https://superuser.com/questions/207034/why-doesnt-find-prune-the-way-i-think-it-should),

but that *accepted* answer doesn't work for me:

Here are my files:

```
$ find . 
.
./resources
./resources/sitewide
./resources/sitewide/test.c
./resources/sitewide/.svn
./resources/sitewide/.svn/test.c
./resources/test.c
./resources/.svn
./resources/.svn/test.c
./test.c
./users
./users/avatars
./users/avatars/test.c
./users/avatars/.svn
./users/avatars/.svn/test.c
./users/test.c
./users/.svn
./users/.svn/test.c
./temporary
./temporary/test.c
./temporary/.svn
./temporary/.svn/test.c
./.svn
./.svn/test.c
```

This is what the result is when using the *accepted answer*:

```
$ find -type d -path '.svn' -prune -o -print
.
./resources
./resources/sitewide
./resources/sitewide/test.c
./resources/sitewide/.svn
./resources/sitewide/.svn/test.c
./resources/test.c
./resources/.svn
./resources/.svn/test.c
./test.c
./users
./users/avatars
./users/avatars/test.c
./users/avatars/.svn
./users/avatars/.svn/test.c
./users/test.c
./users/.svn
./users/.svn/test.c
./temporary
./temporary/test.c
./temporary/.svn
./temporary/.svn/test.c
./.svn
./.svn/test.c
```

There are two problem with the accepted answer, first the .svn are still listed, and second, not only directories but files are also listed.

These problems I actually can fix. but my question is,

**how to find those .c files not under .svn directories?**

I've tried all the following but nothing worked for me:

```
 find .  -path '*/.svn' -prune -name "*.c" -print
 find .  -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -name "*.c" -print
 find .  -path '*/.svn' -prune -name "*.c" -o -print
 find .  -path '*/.svn' -prune -a -name "*.c" -print
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
find .  -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -name "*.c" -print
```

should indeed work, though you might rewrite it

```
find .  -name .svn -prune -o -name "*.c" -print
```

otherwise your find is broken. I tried on 2 versions `find --version`:

```
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.12
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

Comment: Thanks meuh. More Q: The command that I actually ran was "`find .  \( -type f -o -type l \) -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -name "*.c" -print`", but I remove that `\( -type f -o -type l \)` part to simplify my question (I also tried to put a `-o` before `-path`). Now I realize it is that part that is giving me the problem. Please add your answer to that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, got it -- `find . -name .svn -prune -o \( -type f -o -type l \) -name "*.c" -print`

Comment: @xpt glad you found how to do what you wanted. The syntax is fairly painful. I find it useful to think there's an implied `-a` between all options and that *and* binds tighter than *or*.